# Using angular , what is the correct way to cater for page reload/refresh in production

Tags: angular, typescript, deployment, angular-reactive-forms

On my localhost I am able to use `window.location.reload()`without issues however when I publish my application to production I get a 404 error upon calling the code for refreshing. I have seen some examples that point to `window.location.href= '/portal/students/view-student', data.id;` and  `window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/portal/students/view-student', data.id;` as well as the `location.replace()`. What is the actual way of ensuring the reload doesnt return a 404 in production. I have also include the index file of my published app in this post.

```
public onSubmit($event: MouseEvent) {
    //($event.target as HTMLButtonElement).disabled = true;
    this.submitted = true;   
    console.log(this.form.value); 
    if (this.form.invalid) {return;}
      const payload = this.form.value;

      payload.id = this.student.id;

      payload.centerId = this.student.centerId;
      this.studentService.postUrl(`${payload.id}/update-student`,payload)
   
      .subscribe((data) => {      
        this.initForms();  
        Swal.fire('Student Information Updated', 'Student information has been updated.', 'success');
        this.router.navigate(['/portal/students/view-student', data.id]);
        window.location.reload(); 
      });
    
  }
```

Published Index File

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html class="loading" lang="en" data-textdirection="ltr"><head><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
  <base href="/StudentsApp/">

  <title>Students App</title>

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/font-awesome@4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="StudentsApp/assets/fonts/feather/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="StudentsApp/assets/fonts/feather/style.min.css"></noscript>
  <link href="StudentsApp/assets/fonts/line-awesome/css/line-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="StudentsApp/assets/fonts/line-awesome/css/line-awesome.min.css"></noscript>
  <link href="StudentsApp/assets/fonts/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="StudentsApp/assets/fonts/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css"></noscript>
  <link href="StudentsApp/assets/fonts/simple-line-icons/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="StudentsApp/assets/fonts/simple-line-icons/style.min.css"></noscript>
  <link href="StudentsApp/assets/fonts/meteocons/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="StudentsApp/assets/fonts/meteocons/style.css"></noscript>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="StudentsApp/assets/images/ico/apple-icon-120.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="StudentsApp/assets/images/ico/apple-icon-152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="StudentsApp/assets/images/ico/apple-icon-76.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="StudentsApp/assets/images/ico/apple-icon-60.png">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="StudentsApp/assets/images/ico/favicon.ico">

<body class="vertical-layout 1-column blank-page pace-done menu-collapsed menu-hide vertical-overlay-menu" data-open="click" data-menu="vertical-menu-modern" data-col="2-columns">

  <app-main></app-main>

<script src="runtime.91d60757ad11e8be.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.e05052d830462261.js" type="module"></script><script src="scripts.f9627fecd7dd714a.js" defer></script><script src="main.4db38e61597a34f8.js" type="module"></script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: what is the server for your app on production? are you using nginx? or something like cloudfront ?

Comment: Do you really need to refresh the page? What should change afterwards?